# Displaying newest element on top in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a React application. I want to display the last added note on top.

Notes is an array of objects. As you can see I've tried notes.reverse() but somehow it's not working. Elements are still being added to the bottom.

```
     <div>
        {notes.reverse().map((note)=> (
          <NotesCard
            note={note}
            key={note.id}
            setInputText={setInputText}
            setInputTitle={setInputTitle}
            setNotes={setNotes}
            notes={notes}
            setId={setId}
          />
          ))
        }
     </div>
```

I'm using submitHandler function that is triggered on clicking the submit button. The function looks like this:

```
  const submitHandler = () => {
    if (inputText || inputTitle) {
      setNotes([
        ...notes,
        {title:inputTitle , text: inputText, id: Math.random()*1000}
      ]);
    } else {
      alert("Notes are Empty. Type something in textarea.");
    }
    setInputText("");
    setInputTitle("");
    setId("");
  };
```

I'm also using an updateHandler function to update the existing note. Which is triggered on clicking the Update button. Whenever I use splice() or unshift() here to set the updated note on the top chrome stops responding and everything hangs.

```
  const updateHandler = () => {

    for (var i=0; i<notes.length; i++) {
      if (id===notes[i].id) {
        if (inputText || inputTitle) {
          notes.push(
            {title:inputTitle , text: inputText, id: Math.random()*1000}
          );
          setNotes(notes.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
        } else {
          alert("Notes are Empty. Type something in textarea.");
        }
      }
    };

    setInputText("");
    setInputTitle("");
    setId("");
  }
```

Comment: Can you also add the code where you are adding the new object to the notes array.

Comment: can you show me your notes look like ?

Comment: can you please show us how you are adding new elements in `notes`

Comment: @jaybhatt just added the funcition check now.

Comment: @PriyankKachhela just edited the question check now.

Comment: @AnhTuan it looks [{title: 'sometitle', text:'sometext', id: soemid}, {title: 'sometitle', text:'sometext', id: soemid}, {title: 'sometitle', text:'sometext', id: soemid} ......................] like this.

Comment: Your `id` shouldn't be random, can you please have it's value as something incremental in nature, maybe `notes.length + 1` or something. Having a random `id` is as good as misusing `key`.

Comment: Also, can you debug or console log your notes array to see the order before you return, as to how it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add your new objects at first position like below.

```
  const submitHandler = () => {
    if (inputText || inputTitle) {
      setNotes([{
        title: inputTitle,
        text: inputText,
        id: Math.random() * 1000
      }, ...notes]);
    } else {
      alert('Notes are Empty. Type something in textarea.');
    }
    setInputText('');
    setInputTitle('');
    setId('');
  };

  const updateHandler = () => {
    if (inputText || inputTitle) {
      const newCopyNotes = notes.filter(el => el.id !== id);
      setNotes([
        { title: inputTitle, text: inputText, id: Math.random() * 1000 },
        ...newCopyNotes
      ]);
    } else {
      alert('Notes are Empty. Type something in textarea.');
    }

    setInputText('');
    setInputTitle('');
    setId('');
  };
```

Remove `reverse` and map normally

```
     <div>
        {notes.map((note)=> (
          <NotesCard
            note={note}
            key={note.id}
            setInputText={setInputText}
            setInputTitle={setInputTitle}
            setNotes={setNotes}
            notes={notes}
            setId={setId}
          />
          ))
        }
     </div>
```

Comment: I'm using an updateHandler function to update the existing notes. I just added it the questino. Using splice() or unshift() here is causing browser hanging issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer for updateHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the reverse() and add the newNote to the top of notesArray

**FIRST**

instead of  `{notes.reverse().map((note)=> (  //code  ))}`

use `{notes.map((note)=> (    //code   ))}`

**SECOND**

instead of

```
setNotes([
   ...notes,
   {title:inputTitle , text: inputText, id: Math.random()*1000}
]);
```

use

```
setNotes([
   {title:inputTitle , text: inputText, id: Math.random()*1000},
   ...notes
]);
```

Comment: I'm using an updateHandler function also to update the existing note. I just added it in the question. How can I add the updated element on top. Using splice() or unshift() is causing browser hanging issue.

Comment: if you are using it in react NoteCard component, check if you have called update() inside render directly? ideally the error message will be 'max call stack exceeded' in console. at that time its unresponsive, please share code for NotesCard calling update

Comment: I solved the problem. By adding an item in the beginning I accidently created an infinite loop. I just needed to jump into the next element by incrementing i one more time.